# How can I change column width in SharePoint 365?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I created list and when I add values in particular field it does not display information adequately. The column width is too small. It barely fits one or two words maximum. So I want to widen the size of columns. can I do this in sharepoint 365?

Answer (score 0):

You could just click the border of the column, then drag it to adjust the width of the column.[image]